# MKPolyLine isn't showing up on iOS app in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkpolyline

I'm creating a sort of direction/GPS app and so far everything has been sort of easy.

- I've figured out how to find the user's location (with their permission of course)
- I've managed to allow them to set a destination in a quick easy way

However, I've run into a small issue. What I want is for the user to select their destination on the screen and the app will give them the fastest way to arrive there.

Here's my ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var mapOfMaps: MKMapView!
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var center:CLLocationCoordinate2D!
    var SourcePM:MKPlacemark!
    let sourcePlacemark: MKPlacemark! = nil
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        self.mapOfMaps.showsUserLocation = true

        let sourceAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()

        if let location = locationManager.location {
            sourceAnnotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
        }
        let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CardioViewController.action(_:)))
        longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0
        mapOfMaps.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)

        //directionRequest
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations.last
        center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.003, longitudeDelta: 0.003))
        self.mapOfMaps.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        SourcePM = MKPlacemark(coordinate: center, addressDictionary: nil)
    }
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("ERROr " + error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func action(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {
        let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.mapOfMaps)
        let newCoord:CLLocationCoordinate2D = mapOfMaps.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: self.mapOfMaps)

        let newAnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        newAnotation.coordinate = newCoord
        newAnotation.title = "Your Destination"
        mapOfMaps.addAnnotation(newAnotation)
        let anotPM = MKPlacemark(coordinate: newAnotation.coordinate, addressDictionary: nil)


        let source = MKMapItem(placemark: SourcePM)
        let dstn = MKMapItem(placemark: anotPM)

        let directionRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
        directionRequest.source = source
        directionRequest.destination = dstn
        directionRequest.transportType = .Automobile

        // Calculate the direction
        let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)

        // 8.
        directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler() {
            (response, error) in
            if(error == nil && response != nil) {
                for route in response!.routes {
                    var r: MKRoute = route as! MKRoute
                    self.mapOfMaps.addOverlay(r.polyline, level: MKOverlayLevel.AboveRoads)
                }
            }

            let route = response!.routes[0]
            self.mapOfMaps.addOverlay((route.polyline), level: MKOverlayLevel.AboveLabels)


            let rect = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
            self.mapOfMaps.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(rect), animated: true)
        }

    }
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        renderer.alpha = 1
        renderer.lineWidth = 4.0

        return renderer
    }
}
```

to help walk you through my code. My user will press and hold the destination on the map and the app will add an annotation and it **should** give the route. However, all that happens is the annotation will be added to the map, and the map will adjust to show both locations(user's location and annotation location) but no route.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the 'ideal' solution, but it's worth noting that both `locationManager` functions can't work at the same time. I tried commenting one of the `locationManager` functions out and low and behold the other worked perfectly